# как найти квадрат элементов массива затем сложить их

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = [2,4,6]
let out = 0
function solution(x){
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   return (x[i] ** 2)
    //должно получиться 56 но не пойму что делать
   
  }
 }
```

Comment: Что делать - узнать, что же делает return.

Comment: Кстати, если уж используется let - можно использовать его уже везде, вместо var) Последний нужен только если есть цель поддерживать старые браузеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` прерывает выполнение функции и возвращает указанный результат, который можно использовать где-то в другом месте (по умолчанию у всех функций `return undefined`). В вашем случае - цикл сразу прерывается вместе с функцией, возвращая первое же значение `x[0] ** 2` → 4. Нужно сначала посчитать сумму, и только в самом конце вернуть её.

Ну чтобы посчитать сумму - нужна дополнительная переменная, куда все будет добавляться. Самое простое решение будет таким:

```js
let x = [2, 4, 6];
let result = bubu(x);

console.log( result );

function bubu(arr){
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + (arr[i] * arr[i]);
  }
  
  return sum;
}
```

И на эльфийском:

```js
let x = [2, 4, 6];

console.log( x.reduce( (sum, e) => sum += e**2, 0 ) );
```

См. "Стрелочные функции", "метод reduce". Их вначале сложновато понять, так и должно быть)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function solution(x) {
  return x.reduce((r, i) => r + i * i, 0);
}
console.log(solution([2, 4, 6]));
```